# Representation of regular languages by monoids

Tags: reference-request, regular-language, semigroups, monoid

I'm interested in representation of regular languages by monoids, and in particular of how to use this kind of representation to get a recognizer.

I have found some references on the web, but does any survey exist? Where should I start?

Comment: This seems an overly broad question.  Perhaps (since you seem to be a newcomer) looking over some of the existing Questions and Answers will give you an idea about the narrower sort of issue that can be dealt with in some degree of completeness on the site.

Comment: @hardmath: thanks for you answer. You are right, I'm a newcomer, and I'm not a mathematician. So, I try to narrow the question: what is a good reference (book, lecture, article, etc) that explains the relationships between algebra and regular languages to a beginner?

Comment: Perhaps editing your Question to give more detail about your actual interest in regular languages would be appropriate and expedite the chance of a useful response.

Comment: For example, you might point out a resource you find on the web (such as [Algorithms for regular languages that use algebra](http://users.dcc.uchile.cl/~pbarcelo/mikolaj.pdf) or another) and explain what about the paper either whets your interest or fails to meet your need.

Comment: I don't see why this would be an overly broad question. I just know one way to recognize a regular language by a (finite) monoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the survey [Finite semigroups and recognizable languages: an introduction](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/PDF/York.pdf),
published in NATO Advanced Study Institute Semigroups, Formal Languages and Groups, J. Fountain (éd.), 1-32, Kluwer academic publishers, (1995).